# Can`t see my app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Good day.
I made an application on facebook. 
It has canvas URL: http://v-skladchinu.ru/user/main_choose/

Canvas page: http://apps.facebook.com/f-two-apps

And Site URL: http://v-skladchinu.ru

But i can`t see anything by canvas page url. Just blank page.

After i check this situation, i understood, that facebook doesn`t even try to call my server for the application. I put a breackpoint to my code and it looks like facebook doesn`t call for http://v-skladchinu.ru/user/main_choose/ page at all.

Why is it so?

Comment: You app tries to display the login dialog within the iframe, which is not possible. And when using Facebook via HTTPS, you don’t even get that far, because you have no trusted SSL certificate for your app domain …

Comment: So what is the correct algorithm? I need to get "code" by going to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth. I use this "code" to get "access_token" to use facebook API. I do it by going to https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token. But my app is in iFrame in facebook. So how do i achive my goals?

Comment: Either redirect in the top window instance via JavaScript – or just use `FB.login` out of the JS SDK in the first place, much less hassle and also looks nicer.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific? I`m not quite sure what to do...

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: have you followed the basic tutorial? (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/) is it working?

Answer (score 0):

Your page seems to have an SSL certificate problem.

I have tried using your app from https://v-skladchinu.ru:8443/ and it's working fine from there if I click "proceed anyway" on the warning from Chrome.

You may want to try some other free SSL sites like **heroku.com**.

Answer (score 0):

You need a valid SSL certificate, not just a self-signed one. a self-signed certificate is telling the browser that you trust yourself, whereas a valid SSL certificate requires another website to verify you're not a spoof.

Just by googleing `free SSL certificates`, you get some good results. For example, http://cert.startcom.org/ gives you free SSL authentication, and even shows you how to set it up step by step, so I do recommend them. They even insure it for $10'000, which for me is the icing on the cake.

However, if you find out they don't suit your needs there are thousands of other free providers to choose from.